# Как вписать картинку в блок с сохранением пропорций

Tags: css

Есть слайдер (не мною написанный). В нем есть родительский блок, который содержит флек-итемы. Этот блок прокручивается за пределы дисплея при нажатии на стрелки. В флекс-итемах (div, они расширены во весь дисплей) есть картинки обернутые в . Нужно вписать в блок картинку неизвестного размера (размер может быть гораздо больше размера дисплея или гораздо меньше). Блок же тоже может быть разного размера - по размеру дисплея (1920, 1200, 1024, 800 и т. д.). Это нужно для того чтобы этот блок использовался для десктопного и мобильного вида. Пропорции картинки тоже могут быть разные. Нужно чтобы картинка вписывалась в этот блок целиком (если размер картинки больше размера блок - сжималась, если меньше - расширялась до размеров блока), но с сохранением пропорций. Причем может быть так 3600px * 200px - нужно чтобы картинка вписалась в виде тонкой полоски (пропорционально уменьшившись).

Сейчас так:

```
  .imageLink: {
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justifyContent: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .image: {
    object-fit: contain;
  },
```

На больших дисплеях картинка хорошо вписывается, но если ширина больше мобильного дисплея - обрезается по краям

Comment: используйте  `object-fit: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

Впишите картинку как background-image, no-repeat cover center, а родителю выставьте требуемый размер.